# Wordpess the_category(); выводит с ошибкой

Tags: wordpress

Прописал функцию для вывода категории , но вместо этого Вордпресс делает двойной цикл, и выводит стать в целом с ошибкой

```
<?php
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint(get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'posts_per_page' => 9,
                    'category_name'  => 'blog',
                    'paged'          => $paged,
                ) );
                while( $the_query->have_posts() ){
                    $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 article_col">
            <a class="lp_single" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <p class="lp_cat"><?php the_category(); ?></p>
                <div class="lp_thumbnail" style="background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>)"></div>

                <div class="lp_about">
                    <h4 class="lp_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="lp_footer">
                    <div class="arrow_more">&rarr;</div>
                    <div class="lp_seen">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php 
    } 
   wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Код покажите. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6688/220220

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка оказалась в том, что я блок с  обернул с ссылку, а сам функцию вывода категории поставил в тег p.

Либо оставить все как ест, но вместо the_category(), 
писать $category = get_the_category();echo $category[0]->cat_name;